# How to check if same DataRequest is already in progress using RxAlamofire or Alamofire 5 and up?

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift, rxalamofire

My workflow is simple.

I don't need to make the same DataRequest 2 times and need to check wether this request is already in progress.
If request is not in progress I need to make the request if some specific time has passed.

How could I achieve something like this using Alamofire ?
I am using 'Alamofire', '5.2.2' and 'RxAlamofire', '5.6.2' .

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this using `interval` and `flatMapFirst`.